# What is the use the plugs over this deadbolt's bolt holes?

Tags: lock, hole, bolts, deadbolt

When re-keying our house, I came upon these unexpected bolt hole plugs in the deadbolt assembly. Is there a graceful way to remove them? I'd prefer not to take a small prying tool and force them out, to avoid marring the assembly, and I'd like to avoid drilling them out for sure.

[image: lock with unknown bolt blocking pins]

Comment: Those plugs are part of the security of a double cylinder deadbolt, if they were easy to remove, the lock would be easy to open from that side. Typically they are drilled out but if they weren't securely installed you might be lucky and be able to pry them out. You might end up damaging the lock... the price of security.

Comment: Those look to me like press studs . Holding the key cylinder to the face plate. You will find the are solid pins. They are integral to the lock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are screw caps, to prevent nasty people from tampering with the cylinder. They are generally [removed by drilling them out](http://kc.allegion.com/kb/article/how-to-remove-a-double-cylinder-deadbolt/).

Comment: Great link; these plugs were easy enough to remove with a prying device, although it's easy to see that they could have been far worse. I did not damage small flat-head screwdriver I used to remove them with gentle force.